# Java Discord API : Reaction already added

Tags: java, discord, bots, discord-jda

I can't find the solution of my problem. I want to check if a member already added a specific reaction (✅). If he already reacted with that reaction, he can't remove it and he can't put it back. Can someone help me please ? Thank you.

There's my code, maybe it will help you :

First class :

```java
public class TimingStart extends ListenerAdapter{

    public static long ID;
    public static long begin;
    public static long end;
    
    public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
        
        String[] args = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split("\\s");
        Random value = new Random();
        int time = value.nextInt(25);
        time += 5;
        
        if (args[0].equals("!timing")) {
            if (!event.getChannel().getId().equals("730784510932811859")) {
                event.getChannel().sendMessage(event.getMember().getAsMention() + ", if you want to play, go to " + event.getGuild().getTextChannelById(730784510932811859l).getAsMention()).queue();
            
            } else if (event.getChannel().getId().equals("730784510932811859")) {
                EmbedBuilder eb = new EmbedBuilder();
                eb.setColor(0xfcdf03);
                eb.setTitle(Integer.toString(time) + " seconds");
                eb.setDescription("React with ✅ when you think the time is up !");
                event.getChannel().sendMessage(eb.build()).queue(msg -> {
                    msg.addReaction("✅").queue();
                    ID = msg.getIdLong();
                });
                begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Second class, it's here i want to check if he already reacted :

```java
public class TimingReaction extends ListenerAdapter {

    public void onGuildMessageReactionAdd(GuildMessageReactionAddEvent event) {
        
        if (event.getMessageIdLong() == TimingStart.ID && event.getReactionEmote().getName().equals("✅")) {
            TimingStart.end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            double tempsEcoule = ( (double) (TimingStart.end - TimingStart.begin) ) / 1000;
            event.getChannel().sendMessage(event.getMember().getAsMention() + ", you reacted after " + tempsEcoule + " seconds !").queue();
            // If the user already reacted, he can't remove the reaction and put it back.
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question and append the code you wrote so far and having a problem with.

Comment: I just edited to add the code.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite certain that this is not possible.

In order to restrict the user from removing their reaction you would have to cancel their action. The `GuildMessageReactionRemoveEvent` only fires after the reaction is already gone.

A workaround may be to make it insignificant if the user removes their reaction or reacts afterwards.

For example, you could set a boolean to true once the user reacted the first time and only execute code in the `GuildMessageReactionAddEvent` if this boolean is false (and if it is the correct emote of course).